# How to call JavaScript function repeatedly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the JavaScript function repeatedly after the execution.

```
function startSlide(){
        var products = [
                        ['images/product_images/footwear/footwear_1.jpeg'],
                        ['images/product_images/mobile/mobile_1.jpeg'],
                        ['images/product_images/camera/camera_1.jpeg'],
                        ['images/product_images/fashion/fashion_1.jpeg'],
                        ['images/product_images/laptop/laptop_1.jpeg'],
                        ['images/product_images/furniture/furniture_1.jpeg']
                       ];
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            var image = products[i][0];
            imgslider(image, i * 800);
        }
    };

    function imgslider(image, timeout)
    {
          window.setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('imgslider').innerHTML = "";
          var product = document.getElementById('imgslider');
          var elem = document.createElement("img");
          product.appendChild(elem);
          elem.src = image;
          },timeout);
          startSlide();
    }
```

The `startSlide()` function iterates the array and fetch the value from array and call the function `imgslider()`. the `imgslider()` function appends the image to the div.

at the end of the imgslider() i am trying to call the startSlide() so that it could continue the execution.... but its not working. how can i do this?

Comment: So you just want to call a function multiple times? Is it that you want? Why not use either a for loop or a timer?

Comment: Your function doesnt make sense, it's an infinite loop...

Comment: Wouldn't just removing startSlide(); in your imgslider fix it? You're in an endless loop, because in the first iteration of startSlide() you call startSlide() again, making you call it over and over again...

Comment: just follow the code for a second, you're calling `startSlide`, which calls `imgslider` which calls `startSlide` which calls `imgslider`..... it's an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your code is creating an infinite recursion...

Maintianing your code structure you can add a flag to fix the problem

```js
function startSlide() {
  var products = [
    ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=1'],
    ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=2'],
    ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=3'],
    ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=4'],
    ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=5']
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var image = products[i][0];
    imgslider(image, i * 800, i == products.length - 1);
  }
};

function imgslider(image, timeout, last) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('imgslider').innerHTML = "";
    var product = document.getElementById('imgslider');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product.appendChild(elem);
    elem.src = image;

    if (last) {
      setTimeout(startSlide, 800);
    }
  }, timeout);
}
startSlide()
```

```html
<div id="imgslider"></div>
```

---

If you want to loop, then you can use setInterval() instead

```js
function startSlide() {
  var products = [
      ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=1'],
      ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=2'],
      ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=3'],
      ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=4'],
      ['//placehold.it/64X64&text=5']
    ],
    i = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    imgslider(products[i][0]);
    if (++i >= products.length) {
      i = 0
    }
  }, 800);
};

function imgslider(image) {
  document.getElementById('imgslider').innerHTML = "";
  var product = document.getElementById('imgslider');
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  product.appendChild(elem);
  elem.src = image;
}
startSlide()
```

```html
<div id="imgslider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `window.setTimeout` only calls the function once, so you should use `window.setInterval` instead. Something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function () { /* code to update picture... */ }, 3000);
```

If it's still not working you can check the console log for errors.
That's <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Chrome.